# Visual Cron and Windows task scheduler executing a powershell script with unexpected results

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

I will preface this by saying I am not really the in the top echelon of programming, be it powershell or others, so please understand my code works to do what I need.  Or it was until earlier this month.

```
$uri = 'https://playbook2.domain.com/data/folder/export/24125'
$of = '\\domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\DCCD Projects.xlsx'
$sf = '\\domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\DCCD Modified.csv'

function Get-Data {
wget $uri -outfile $of -UseDefaultCredentials
}

function CSV-Creation {
if (Test-Path $sf) {
    Remove-Item $sf
    }

$excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($of)
$page = 'Project Summary'
$ws = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}
Start-Sleep 5
$cells=$ws.Cells
$range = $ws.UsedRange
$rows = $range.Rows.Count
$dataDate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
$cols = $range.Columns.Count 
$newCol = $cols + 1
$ws.Cells(1, $newCol).Value = "Snapshot"

for($i = 2; $i -ne $rows+1; $i++){
    $ws.Cells($i, $newCol).Value="$dataDate"
    $ws.Cells($i, $newCol).NumberFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"
}

$excel.visible = $true

$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs('\\domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\DCCD Modified.csv',6)

Close-Excel

}

function Close-Excel {

Start-Sleep 1

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ws)|out-null
$ws=$null

Start-Sleep 1

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)|out-null
$Workbook=$null

Start-Sleep 1

$excel.Quit()

Start-Sleep 1

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)|out-null
$excel=$null

[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}

function Clean-Dates {

(Get-Content $sf) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', '$3-$1-$2'} | Set-Content $sf

}

function Clean-Downloads {
Remove-Item $of
}

Get-Data
CSV-Creation
Clean-Dates
Clean-Downloads
```

Now this script, when run via powershell by right clicking or opened in the ISE and run results in the expected output of a csv file.

The starting WGET gives an excel file of ~16KB and the resultant csv is ~21KB.  Exact contents matching not withstanding, the inspection of the data at a level of looking and not just skimming seems to show it all there after the script has completed from powershell or powershell ise.

plugging this in to visual cron or task scheduler since about 5/10/2016 results in a csv file that is empty; 1KB.  I made no changes to the script between then and now.  I haven't made any changes to excel that I am aware of and only regular windows updates as required by the company have happened.

First question is, what can I check to figure out why this results in empty files since it is executing fine in powershell itself.

Next is, am I doing something so egregious in my code that it might be causing this type of thing?  if so which section does your evaluation say I should focus on?

Comment: Never run things in the ISE... `powershell.exe` is where scripts will be executed 99.9% of the time.

Comment: I only run in ISE when I have been making changes to see if they execute there and then verify that right click run with powershell also works.  To clarify, I had not made any changes when this stopped working and when it was working.

Comment: FWIW, I don't recommend running Office applications from the Task Scheduler because [they are designed for interactive use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: Bill, I understand; is there a better way to take an excel file to csv without the use of excel? Edit: that sound a bit dumb, what I mean is in a way that avoids the com objects and such?

Comment: Have you searched?

Comment: If you try a `Get-Command *csv*` you'll find two cmdlets in particular that'll let you avoid opening and playing with excel (ConvertFrom-CSV and ConvertTo-CSV).  You may also need "Get-Content".  In my experience, releasing the com object and doing the garbage collection isn't always the easiest, especially if you have other office programs up and running.  I'm not sure exactly what goes on, but I know they don't play nice.  I think the point everyone is trying to make is that you really should be using native cmdlets rather than playing with COM objects.  I hope this helps @Shenanigator

Comment: If the data was coming in in .CSV that would probably work great and I would never touch excel.  It's not.  It is coming in xlsx form which is microsoft's compressed XML, etc.  Import-Excel seems to maybe offer the ability to avoid excel for dealing with the excel file to begin with.  I am trying to see if I can get the team that owns the output source to provide CSV to begin with and avoid excel completely.